# How to filter a dataframe taking into account two columns with different labels

Tags: python, pandas

this is my first question here and I am new with Python.
I have this 2 simple dataframe that I create to illustrate my problem

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'dr': ['A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'E','F','G','H'],
                    'mx': [1, 1,1, 1, 2, 2,2,2],
                    'mu': [100, 600, 1100,1600, 100, 600,1100,1600]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'mx': [1, 2],
                    'mu_min': [100, 600],
                    'mu_max': [1100, 1600]})
   dr  mx    mu
0  A   1   100
1  D   1   600
2  B   1  1100
3  C   1  1600
4  E   2   100
5  F   2   600
6  G   2  1100
7  H   2  1600
   mx  mu_min  mu_max
0   1     100    1100
1   2     600    1600
```

What a want is to filter de df1 dataframe, taking into account the min value and max value of 'mu' for each 'mx'
I expect something like this

```
   dr  mx    mu
0  A   1   100
1  D   1   600
2  B   1  1100
5  F   2   600
6  G   2  1100
7  H   2  1600
```

I have tried mask like this:

```
mask1=df1['mu']>=df2['mu_min']
mask2=df1['mu']<=df2['mu_max']
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I'm having trouble knowing how to google a solution to this problem, that's why I'm writing here to see if someone can help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try via `merge():`

```
out=df1.merge(df2,on='mx')
```

Finally filter out via `between()` method and use `drop()` method to remove unwanted column:

```
out=out[out['mu'].between(out['mu_min'],out['mu_max'])].drop(['mu_min','mu_max'],1)
```

output of `out`:

```
    dr  mx  mu
0   A   1   100
1   D   1   600
2   B   1   1100
5   F   2   600
6   G   2   1100
7   H   2   1600
```